# convergence of series with $k!$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

check if the following series converges:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \dfrac{(k-1)!!}{k!!}$

where $k!!=k(k-2)(k-4)(k-6)...$

I came across this exercise while going trough some old exams. I'm pretty sure we have to bound the sequence and apply Leibniz-criteria but after a while i gave up. If you have a little Hint for me just to get me strted , that would be great.

Comment: Here is a precise definition of $k!!$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

Comment: so $k!!$ is not the same as $(k!)!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $a_k = (k-1)!!/k!!$, so that we're looking at the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k a_k$. Notice that the odd terms are exactly the normalized central binomial coefficients:
$$
a_{2n} = \frac1{4^n} \binom{2n}n.
$$
By [known asymptotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient), $a_{2n} \sim 1/\sqrt{\pi n}$ as $n$ grows large. Similarly,
$$
a_{2n-1} = \frac1{2na_{2n}} \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2n} = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt n}
$$
as $n$ grows large. Therefore
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2N} (-1)^k a_k &= \sum_{n=1}^N ( -a_{2n-1}+a_{2n} ) \\
&\approx  \sum_{n=1}^N \bigg( {-}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt n}+\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}} \bigg) \sim c\sqrt N
\end{align*}
where $c = -\sqrt\pi+2/\sqrt\pi < 0$. So the sum diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: To get this exact asymptotic formula for the partial sum, putting in the error terms is indeed important (although in this case it's trivial to do). But simply to prove divergence, all one needs is a constant $b<0$ for which $-a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}<b/\sqrt n$ for sufficiently large $n$; and the existence of such a $b$ follows just from the limiting statement - no error term necessary.

Comment: Excuse my previous comment, your approach is perfect, +1. You just have a little mistake, I think (your $c$ is actually $>0$). In fact, it is $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$ and $a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)a_{2n}}$. So $a_{2n}-a_{2n+1}\sim c/\sqrt{n}$ with $c=1/\sqrt{\pi}-\sqrt{\pi}/2<0$. So directly, the partial sums are equivalent to $2c\sqrt{N}$ as you said. No need to look at the error term for anything in what you said.

Comment: I think I fixed the errors - please point out if you see others.